# PHP Error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have this error in wordpress

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in... on line 20

line 20:<img src="<?php echo get_option('logo')['logo'];?>" height="243" width="187">
```

NB:in the localhost in my pc it works but when i upload it doesn't work it show me this error

Comment: Show the `php` code on line `20`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include the code that is generating the error. This will help us answer. An even better option (when relevant) would be to include a live link to your problem page or maybe a jsfiddle/codepen.

Comment: my crystal ball tells me it is somewhere near line 20. maybe you should post the code around that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local and Wordpress versions of PHP are different. For your Wordpress version of PHP, your code should look like this:

```
<img src="<?php 
    $x=get_option('logo');
    echo $x['logo'];?>" height="243" width="187">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version is too low for this kind of syntax:

```
<?php echo get_option('logo')['logo'];?>
```

Instead use:

```
<?php
$option = get_option('logo');
echo $option['logo'];
?>
```